# Quickest way to edit document properties in a header?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have some fields inside a header of a Word document and I want the fields to be editable in a quick way. [This](https://youtu.be/zmFyzdhKH_M?t=338) video suggests a panel that can be opened, but I think that is only available in older versions of Word.

Is there a quick way to access the place to edit the field value without going into file>info>properties?

Comment: Can you clarify your question. Are you trying to reach advanced document properties like those shown in the panel in the video or trying to edit something in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you want to edit document properties (like in the video) or if you want to add references and be able to edit those quickly. I'm going to assume the former.

On the ribbon bar, click the View tab, then click 'View Document Properties' on the right.

[image]

If this is something you need to do often, consider adding a shortcut to the Quick Access Toolbar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should not have things to be edited in your header or footer. It complicates things for the user. Instead, put it in the body of the [template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm) being used to create the document (often in a Cover Page) and then use a [StyleRef Field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF) in the header/footer to reflect the information on all pages.

I do not know if this is a Document Property Content Control inserted using Quick Parts Document Property *(Method 3 in the video you linked uses these.)* or a DocProperty Field. **I'm assuming you want to edit the document property.**

If it is a **Content Control**, you can double click in your header area and then directly edit it.

If it is a **DocProperty *Field***, you need to access advanced properties. This is more complex. It can be done with either a keyboard shortcut or a QAT button. You would then want to update the field. Print Preview will usually accomplish this. [Dealing with Fields in Microsoft Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501)

### [Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330)

*[Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) to my Article about doing this.*
[image: Screenshot Assign Keyboard Shortcut Dialog]

### [Add a QAT Button](https://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm#PageStart)

*[Link](https://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm#PageStart) to my page on QAT Modification*
[image: QAT Modification dialog]

*Note that the Advanced Document Properties and the Document Property Content Controls under Quick Parts do not have a 1:1 correspondence.*

- [Repurposing Document Property Content Controls](https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart) (my page)
- [Enhanced Document Property Controls](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/EnhancedDocProp_AddIn.html) by Greg Maxey

Disclosure: All links are to things I have written except the last link to Greg Maxey's page.